# wordpress frontend posts to automatically post on user's facebook timeline

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

Can someone please give me some hand on how should I setup this flow on my website:

1. User is already connected to the site with facebook connect with these permissions: email, read_friendlists, publish_stream, publish_actions. And that all works fine.
2. User submits an article from frontend in wordpress successfully.

What I want to do is when `add_post()` action is triggered (using custom theme) and successfully submits article in wp, I would also like to post the same article to the user's fb timeline.

Believe me I've read all the darn documentation in FB dev but no straightforward example on how I could do that.

They mention using curl to graph api , but how to use it? With php or javascript? Maybe you will have any working example cod so I could have a look?